# Are finite $G$-spectra idempotent complete?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, equivariant-homotopy

**Question:** Let $G$ be a compact Lie group (you can assume that $G$ is finite if you like). Is the category of finite $G$-spectra idempotent complete?

Here, by "finite $G$-spectra", I mean those objects in the category of genuine $G$-spectra which can be constructed via a finite number of sums and cofiber sequences from orbit cells $S^n \wedge (G/H)_+$ where $H \subseteq G$ is a closed subgroup. This includes all representation spheres. By "category", I mean either the stable $\infty$-category or the triangulated category, whichever you prefer (in the stable case, a category is idempotent complete iff its homotopy category is, so it doesn't affect the question.)

When $G$ is trivial, the answer is *yes*, but I suspect the answer in general is *no*, -- maybe already for $G = C_2$?

By a [theorem of Thomason](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1017932514274), triangulated subcategories of a triangulated category $\mathcal T$ which generate $\mathcal T$ under splitting of idempotents are in bijection with subgroups of $K_0(\mathcal T)$. So another way to phrase the question is the following: let $\mathcal T$ be the category of compact $G$-spectra. Then is t$K_0(\mathcal T)$ generated as a group by the classes of $G$-orbits $\Sigma^n(G/H)_+$?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, and you can get a counterexample from a finitely-dominated finite CW-complex with nontrivial Wall finiteness obstruction (this obstruction factors over taking stabilisation).

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams I'm confused -- when $G$ is trivial, I believe the answer is _yes_... I don't have a proof in front of me, but I think the idea is to use that any compact object in spectra must have finitely-generated homology, and to use this to construct a model of it with finitely many cells.

Comment: I think the standard proof for spectra will work here as well (using Mackey functors valued homology) but it's too late here for me to try to write a proof :)

Comment: @Tim Sure, not every group has nontrivial reduced projective class group, but some do, e.g. $G=\mathbb{Z}/23$.

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams Now I'm more confused -- $K_0(\mathbb Z[\pi_1(X)])$ is where the Wall finiteness obstruction lives, but $\pi_1(X)$ has nothing to do with the $G$ in the question with respect to which things are equivariant. Moreover, the Wall finiteness obstruction vanishes for any 1-fold suspension space... Are you suggesting that the category of finite spectra is _not_ idempotent complete? If so, then I think that's incorrect. If not, then how does equivariance play a role in your suggestion? Are you talking about some form of equivariant Wall finiteness obstruction?

Comment: Oh -- are you saying to take $X$ to be some finitely-dominated CW complex with nonvanishing Wall obstrutction, and then to regard the universal cover $\tilde X$ as a $G$-space for $G = \pi_1(X)$, and then think that maybe $\Sigma^\infty \tilde X$ might be a finitely-dominated but not finite $G$-spectrum (which happens to be Borel)?

Comment: @Tim. Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I think I'd buy that either Oscar's suggestion or user171227's suggestion would probably give something which is not finite as a _Borel_ $G$-spectrum, but because the notion of being a projective $\mathbb Z[G]$-module is closely tied up with freeness of the $G$-action, I wonder if such constructions might nevertheless be finite as _genuine_ $G$-spectra?

Comment: If $G$ is cyclic of prime order $p$ and with generator $g \in G$, you can invert $p(g-1) \in \pi_0(S[G])$.  This process kills $S^n \wedge G/G_+$ completely and the chains of the resulting spectrum are naturally modules over $R = \mathbb{Z}[p^{-1},\zeta_p]$.  For a finite spectrum $V$ the chains $C_*(V[(p(g-1))^{-1}];\mathbb{Z})$ will therefore admit a filtration where the associated graded is a direct sum of shifts of finitely generated _free_ $R$-modules, which can presumably be ruled out in $K_0(R)$.

Comment: @DenisNardin The tension between your intuition and Oscar's almost-complete answer is killing me!

Answer (score 9):

I think the correct setting to look at this question is that of

W. Lück, "Transformation groups and algebraic K-theory". Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1408. Mathematica Gottingensis. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1989.

Lück considers the $K$-theory of the category $\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{Or}(G)$ of functors $\mathrm{Or}(G)^{op} \to \mathbb{Z}\text{-mod}$, and in particular proves (Theorem 10.36) that there is a decomposition
$$K_0(\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{Or}(G)) \cong \bigoplus_{\text{conjugacy classes of } H \leq G} K_0(\mathbb{Z}\pi_0(WH))$$
where $WH = N_G(H)/H$ is the Weyl group of $H \leq G$. (Stated in this way it is valid for $G$ a compact Lie group.) The image of a functor $M : \mathrm{Or}(G)^{op} \to \mathbb{Z}\text{-mod}$ in the $H$th component is
$$M(G/H)/Im(M(\phi) \text{ for all nonisomorphisms } \phi : G/H \to G/H')$$
with its evident $\pi_0(WH)$-action.

By taking $G$-cellular chains, a finitely-dominated $G$-CW-complex or $G$-CW-spectrum $Y$ has an Euler characteristic
$$\chi(Y) \in K_0(\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{Or}(G))$$
which satisfies inclusion-exclusion as usual. Under the splitting described above one calculates that
$$\chi(S^n \wedge G/H_+) = (-1)^n [\mathbb{Z}\pi_0(WH)].$$
Thus any finite $G$-spectrum $Y$ in the sense of the question has $\chi(Y)$ given by a sum of such  terms, and so the image
$$Wall(Y) \in \bigoplus_{\text{conjugacy classes of } H \leq G} \widetilde{K}_0(\mathbb{Z}\pi_0(WH))$$
of $\chi(Y)$ in this quotient obstructs $Y$ being equivalent to a finite $G$-spectrum.

Lück also shows (Theorem 14.12) that all elements of $K_0(\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{Or}(G))$ arise from some finitely-dominated $G$-CW-complex.

Putting this together, I think it follows that finite $G$-spectra are idempotent-complete if and only if we have $\widetilde{K}_0(\mathbb{Z}\pi_0(WH))=0$ for all $H \leq G$.

Comment: If $Wall(Y) \neq 0$, then this shows that $Y$ is not equivalent to a finite $G$-spectrum, but how do you see that $Wall(Y) = 0$ implies that $Y$ _is_ equivalent to a finite $G$-spectrum? Could there be other obstructions?

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about how to regard $\chi(Y)$ as a stable invariant. I can see that the inclusion-exclusion property implies that $\chi(\Sigma Y) = -\chi(Y)$. So assuming that the stabilization of compact $G$-spaces can be constructed via a Spanier-Whitehead type construction, I buy that $\chi$ is well-defined on the stabilization of $G$-spaces. But the stabilization of $G$-spaces is only _naive_ $G$-spectra. In order to pass to _genuine_ $G$-spectra, it seems we need to know how $\chi$ interacts with smashing with representation spheres. Perhaps that's also in Lück's book...

Comment: @TimCampion: I think that for the approach you are suggesting you just need to show that $\chi(\text{regular representation sphere})$ is a unit in $K_0(\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{Or}(G))$, which I have not done but am sure it is. What I had in mind was instead taking the "Mackey-functor valued cellular chains" of the $G$-CW-complex $Y$, and letting $\chi(Y)$ be the underlying complex of presheaves on $\mathrm{Or}(G)$.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries: Lück shows that for $G$-CW-complexes it is the only obstruction. I don't see any step that would not go through for $G$-spectra.

Comment: This may be a bit late to the battle, but I think one doesn't need to go through spaces, iirc you can prove that $K(Sp_G) = \bigoplus_{[H]\leq G} K(\mathbb S[W_GH])$, which on $K_0$ immediately shows that your description of $K_0(\mathbb Z Or(G))$ is $K_0(Sp_G)$, so that any class in the RHS is realized as a $K$-theory class of a compact $G$-spectrum (in particular if one of them is nonzero, you get an obstruction to finiteness). Conversely, a theorem of Thomason shows that a dense subcategory is entirely determined by its image on $K$-theory, so this shows that it's the only obstruction

Answer (score 5):

To complement Oscar's more systematic answer, let me expand my comment about the case $G = \mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ for a prime number $p$, where the answer is *no* when $\tilde{K}_0(\mathbf{Z}[G]) \neq 0$.  Candidate non-finite retracts of finite $G$-spectra have already been presented in [the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388784/are-finite-g-spectra-idempotent-complete#comment990097_388784), to see that they are not equivalent to finite genuine spectra we can use that the natural homomorphisms $$\tilde{K}_0(\mathbf{Z}[G]) \to \tilde{K}_0(\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p]) \to \tilde{K}_0(\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}])$$
are both isomorphisms.  The first of these is an isomorphism by a [theorem of Rim](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970033).  To see that the second map is an isomorphism we use that $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}] = \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,(\zeta_p-1)^{-1}]$ and that $(\zeta_p - 1) \subset \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p]$ is a prime ideal (see e.g., the proofs of Lemma 1.3 and 1.4 on page 2 of [Washington's book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1934-7), in fact $p = (\zeta_p - 1)^{p-1} u$ for $u \in \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p]^\times$), so exercise 3.8(b) in [chapter I of Weibel's K-book](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eweibel/Kbook/Kbook.I.pdf) applies.

For any genuine $G$-spectrum $X$, the fixed points $X^e$ for the trivial subgroup come with an action of $G$, so we can form $$C_* (X;\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}]) := C_* (X^e;\mathbf{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]} \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}].$$
This defines an exact functor $C_* (-;\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}])$ from the stable $\infty$-category of genuine $G$-spectra to $\mathcal{D} (\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}])$.  This functor sends $\Sigma^\infty_+ (G/e) \mapsto \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}]$ and an easy exercise shows that it sends $\Sigma^\infty_+ (G/G) \mapsto 0$.  Therefore a genuine $G$-spectrum which is finite in your sense will be sent to a compact object in $\mathcal{D} (\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}])$ representing $0 \in \tilde{K}_0(\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}])$.

Any element of $\tilde{K}_0(\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}]) $
may be represented by the image under this functor of a retract of
$ ( \Sigma^\infty_+ G ) ^{\oplus n} $ for some $n$.
Some such retract then won't be finite when $\tilde{K}_0 (\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p,p^{-1}]) \neq 0$.